# How to start forever service for angular + NativeScript project?

Tags: angular, nativescript

On live server ,I have setup Angular + NativeScript shared Project on this path `var/www/html/crons/SourceCode` according to below url

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-build-a-pwa-an-ios-app-and-an-android-app-from-one-codebase

Now I have generated build successfully , then I upload that build folder name crons to on this path var/www/html/crons/SourceCode/crons

I start angular server using `ng serve` command, but I need to start it with and run indefinitely, so I don't want to start angular server everyday

Comment: Sorry, may I ask what does your mobile application has anything to do with starting a service on server?

Comment: It is shared code project. So for the mobile application I just submit the build .There is no need to start server for.mobbile apps, server start requirements need only in web build

Comment: You should not use ng serve for production. If you have an apache server, you just have to upload it to the particular path and make sure it's accessible on browser. Go through the deployment guide for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to read up Angular's [guide on deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).

When it comes to deploying your application on a live server, you should not be using the `ng serve` command. The most practical and obvious reasons are the speed, and huge bundle size.

Instead, your first step should be the [build](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#basic-deployment-to-a-remote-server) it with the production flag

```
ng build --prod
```

Of course, there are a ton of things you could have done to customise your build process, but this is the most basic and straightforward way of building your application.

The built files will be stored in the `dist` folder, and this is what you should be using to be deployed on your servers. From there, you can use forever, pm2, docker, or a bunch of other tools to run your application.

Comment: Yes I did it all , is there separate command for angular server start and for forever service start? or do I need to start angular server with forever service?

Comment: No, do not use `ng serve` for that purpose. May I know what is the command you use to run/deploy it?

Comment: Ng serve -- host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 , this command I put from build folder on live ..As I told I have created build and uploaded  on live server .Now just want to start server once with forever service . So that thing I don't know